# Get the age of a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have scenario where i have to create a list of files which are older than 1 year and also find the age by how much is it older, i have got the list, only issue is getting the age, when i try to use the LastAccessTime i get error as cannot convert string to system.datetime , here is my code

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$path = "\\fbd-vs1\publicnew"

get-childitem $path -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime - 
lt $time} | select Directory,Name,CreationTime, lastaccesstime , LastWriteTime|
export-csv "D:\AJay\Time\Last.csv" -notypeinfo
```

Here is the code for getting age

```
$StartDate=(GET-DATE)
$UserData = "D:\AJay\Time\Last.csv"
$CSVFile = Import-CSV $UserData
Foreach ($ThisUser in $CSVFile)
 {
  //here error as cannot convert string to system.datetime (when i take the value directly it converts to date.)
   $EndDate=[datetime]$ThisUser.LastAccessTime

    $day = NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate |select Days

 Select-Object *,@{Name='Age';Expression={$day}} | Export-Csv "D:\AJay\Time\New.csv" -NoTypeInformation
  }
```

if you have any other solution please let me know

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$ThisUser.LastAccessTime` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6):

```
# Create an additional calculated property with the number of Days since the file was last accessed.
# You can also shorten the key names to be 'l', and 'e', or use Name instead of Label.
$days = @{l="Days";e={((Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime).Days}}
# You can also shorten the name of your label key to 'l' and your expression key to 'e'.
Get-ChildItem $PSHOME -File | Select-Object Name, $size, $days
```

You can use this expression in your code. I've included a Sort-Object to see it easier:

```
$days = @{l="Days";e={((Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime).Days}}
get-childitem $path -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime |Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $time} | select Directory,Name,CreationTime, lastaccesstime ,$days, LastWriteTime |export-csv "D:\AJay\Time\Last.csv" -notypeinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to a `datetime`, casting on its own doesn't work here.  `ParseExact` will be your friend here, the 2nd parameter needs to match the input source of the date format of first parameter.

In this example, it is expecting the last access time to be like '05-12-2019' and will return a `datetime` object.

```
[datetime]::parseexact($ThisUser.LastAccessTime, 'dd-MM-yy', $null)
```

> OUTPUT: 05 December 2019 00:00:00

Comment: Hi Hardcoded thanks for the input, i added you line in front of $EndDate = , i get days output ,but also error after days and then again days as output recursively, the error is                       Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:7 char:5
+     $EndDate=[datetime]::parseexact($ThisUser.LastAccessTime, 'dd-MM- ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: Hi Ajay, as I mentioned the 2nd perameter is the date time structure it is expecting which is whatever the date format you have stored in the csv file, if it doesnt match it will throw the exception as not a recognized valid datetime.